# Find entry point in C# MongoDB Driver

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, dll

I am trying to use the .NET MongoDB Driver in Excel VBA, by way of Declare statement:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function MongoClient Lib "C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\mongodb.driver\2.19.1\lib\net472\MongoDB.Driver.DLL" () As Object

Sub Main()

DbConnection

End Sub

Sub DbConnection()

Dim mymongo As Object
Set mymongo = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")

End Sub
```

On run, the error "Can't find DLL entry point MongoClient" comes up.

I have used dotPeek, ISpy, Visual Studio, Notepad++ to try and discern the entry point to the DLL, but I don't know what I'm looking for. Can someone please suggest how to use these tools to find the correct entry point?

Thanks